# Use string as route parameter in WebApi controller. Error 405

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use string as parameter in WebApi controller. I set custom route as follow [Route("api/sets/{setid}")] but this doesn't help as well. Controller code is quite simple and I'm really can't get what is problem of error 405. Here is Controller code:

```
public class SetDetails
        {
            public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
            public string ItemUrl { get; set; }
            public string ItemImageUrl { get; set; }
            public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        }
        // GET: api/Sets
        [Route("api/sets/{setid}")]
        public IQueryable<SetDetails> GetDetails(string setid)
        {
            var sd = from a in db.Sets
                     where a.SetID.Contains(setid)
                     select new SetDetails
                     {
                         ItemDescription = a.ItemDescription,
                         ItemName = a.ItemName,
                         ItemUrl = a.ItemUrl,
                         ItemImageUrl = a.ItemImageUrl,
                         ItemPrice = a.ItemPrice
                     };
            return sd.AsQueryable();
        }
```

And here is WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "PreppApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you making the request? I suspect you are POSTing to that route but the method is only configured to respond to GETs.

Comment: I'm querying controller this way: 
            $.getJSON("/api/sets?setid=" + setid, self.items);

Comment: Exactly, this method configured to respond GET, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: I don't see why you are sending self.items as the data parameter. Inspect in Fiddler or F12 what request is actually crafted by JQuery. I think you want to do: $.getJSON("/api/sets/" + setid)

Comment: @Crowcoder, you're right. Just normally I'm using getJson this way - with ?paramname. Anyway, it's working. Please add this as answer. self.items this is KnockoutJs observableArray object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending the query string parameters, let WebApi routing pull it out of the last section of the URL

```
$.getJSON("/api/sets/" + setid);
```